# Cache for heap memory access

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver, cpu-cache

In general desktops have 2 kinds of CPU cache to faster memory access.

1) Instruction cache -> to speed up executable instructions.

2) Data cache -> to speed up data fetch and store.

As per my understanding, Instruction cache operates on code segment of a program and Data cache operates on data segment of program. is this right?

Is there no cache advantage for memory allocated from heap? is heap memory access is covered in data cache?

Answer (score 0):

> Instruction cache operates on code segment of a program and Data cache operates on data segment of program. Is this right?

No, CPU is unaware about segments.

*Instruction* cache is for all **execution accesses**, whether they are performed inside code segment, or in the heap as dynamically created code.

Data cache is for all other, *non-execution accesses*. Data can be in the data segment, heap, or even in the code segment as constants.

Comment: Thanx for your response. Can you elaborate more on data cache, what exactly goes to this?

Comment: When an instruction attemps to read something from memory, it firstly checks the data cache. If value at given address is already in a cache and valid, it is used by the instruction. When an instruction attemps to write something to memory, corresponded value in a cache either updated or invalidated (marked as invalid). All above may depend on *cache policy*, defined for memory region, which is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, Instruction cache operates on code segment of a program and Data cache operates on data segment of program. is this right?
>
> Is there no cache advantage for memory allocated from heap? is heap memory access is covered in data cache?

Memory is memory. The CPU can't tell the difference between the heap and the data.

Instruction caches usually just start with the address in the program counter and grab the next N bytes. The CPU still can't tell if its a code segment or a data segment.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a program, this gets translated into machine readable binary. When CPU executes instructions, it fetches this binary, decodes, what it mean and then execute. Basically this binary tells CPU what instructions it has to execute. If this binary was only stored in main memory, then during each fetch stage, CPU has to access main memory, which is really bad. Instead what we do is to store, some of it in a cache, closer to the CPU. Since this cache only contain binary information related to the instructions to be executed, we call it instruction cache. Now instructions need data to operate. In your high level code you might have something like
`arrayA[i] = (arrayB[i] + arrayC[i])` which will translate into a machine instruction something similar to

`ADD memLocationStoredInRegisterA, memLocationStoredInRegisterB, memLocationStoredInRegisterC`

This instruction is stored in instruction cache, but the data, i.e arrayA, arrayB and arrayC will be stored in another portion of memory. Again it will be useless to access main memory, each time this instruction is executed. Therefore we store some of this in another cache, which we call data cache.